# Complex query over two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
table1:
id
--
1
2
3

table2: (left out primary index)
id2 | cond
----------
3   | 1
3   | 0
2   | 1
2   | 1
2   | 0
```

I would need to construct a query that implicitly calculates this intermediary table:

```
temp:
id | c1 | c2
------------
1  | 0  | 2
2  | 2  | 2
3  | 1  | 2
```

with `c1 = countRows(id2 == id && cone == 1)` and `c2 == countRows(id2 = 2 && cond == 1)`.

and then selects `SELECT id FROM temp ORDER BY ABS(c1 - c2)*RAND()`.

My current try is kind of like:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(t1.id2) AS c1, COUNT(t2.id2) AS c2
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN (table2 AS t1) ON id=t1.id2 LEFT JOIN (table2 AS t2) ON t2.id2=2
WHERE t1.cond=1 AND t2.cond=1
GROUP BY t1.id2
ORDER BY ABS(c1 - c2)*RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Which has multiple problems:

1. It doesn't select rows with no entry in table2
2. It doesn't correctly count
3. There seems to be a problem with group columns (c1, c2) in the ORDER BY part 3.

Help would be appreciated.

---

**Update:**

- table1 represents players for example
- table2 would be rounds played, with cond indicating a win
- c1 represents the rounds won by each player
- c2 represents the rounds won by a reference player (player 2 in this case)

Comment: But id2 never equals 1 !?!?

Comment: Yeah, there is no entry for it, so c1 for id=1 must be 0 (which I don't get to work!)

Comment: You can think of table2 being turns in a game and player 1 hasn't played yet

Comment: 1. is because of `t2.cond=2` in your `WHERE` clause. Move that condition to your `LEFT JOIN` for `t2`

Comment: Please explain more clearly what `c2` represents.

Comment: @Strawberry c2 is the count for id2 = 2, because in this instance i want to compare the scores of all players with the score of player 2

Comment: @FuzzyTree Thanks, so ... LEFT JOIN (table2 AS t2) ON t2.id2=x WHERE t2.cond=2 ?

Comment: So there are players now? And no. Not "WHERE" but "AND"

Comment: What requirement does `LIMIT 1` implement?

Comment: @Strawberry The players / rounds is a possible interpretation of the tables and queries, and thanks.

Comment: If `c2` is a count for `id2 = 2`, then it should have the same value for every row.

Comment: @PM77-1 To select one player, but that one isn't mentioned in the post, sorry.

Comment: In your intermediary table, `c2` has 1 on the third row...

Comment: @shmosel Yes it should. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, SUM(IFNULL(t2.cond, 0) = 1) AS c1, (SELECT SUM(cond = 1) FROM table2 WHERE id2 = 2) AS c2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id2
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY ABS(SUM(IFNULL(t2.cond, 0) = 1) - c2) * RAND();
```

Comment: Great this works! You couldn't believe how happy I am ;)

Comment: No problem. You can leave out the `= 1` if `cond` is a boolean field as I suspect.

Comment: You suspect right, but after battling with SQL for a while I didn't want to make any stupid mistakes anymore and started writing out everything I wasn't sure about. But good to know!

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if the first part of your query is returning valid results..

```
SELECT
    t1.id AS id
    COUNT(t2.id2) AS c1
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t3.id2 = 2 THEN t3.id2 ELSE NULL END) as c2
FROM
    table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 as t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id2 AND t2.cond = 1
    LEFT JOIN table2 as t3
        ON t3.id2 = 2 AND t3.cond = 1

GROUP BY
    t2.id2,
    t3.id2
```

Can you provide schema?

Comment: That CASE condition looks like you maybe mean either `SUM(CASE WHEN t2.id2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` or `COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.id2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` (which produce equivalent results)

Comment: Absolutely right! thanks. Also it just occurred to me that there's a need to have another JOIN to populate t2.id2=2 separately.

Comment: If you use `COUNT(CASE...)` you need to do `ELSE NULL` because the 0 would still return a row.  If you use `SUM(CASE..)` then `ELSE 0` is ok.

Comment: As @shmosel mentioned, t3.id2 = 2 AND t3.cond = 1 will return same amount of records for each row in t1...

Comment: @JA Okay, I get 1 | 0 | 2, 2 | 4 | 4, 3 | 4 | 4